# I have a google script that pulls information from a google form and stores it into a sheet. It worked fine until last week and the functions failed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form that has a button that should pull data from the user form and place into the appropriate place in the sheet. It worked fine until last week when it simply stopped working.  I don't get an error message it just says under the status in the execution log "Failed."
In debugging I have determined it's at the point in the userform html where the script is called that the function is failing. I wrote one line function simply to get the log to write "test."

```
function test(){
  Logger.log('test');
}
```

The above code when ran from the editor by clicking run works fine, as expected.

```
function TestClick(){
      google.script.run.test();
      }
```

Though when I click the button to activate this line of code I get the "failed" message under status.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Hi there @JoshWexler! The steps described to replicate the issue doesn't generate it on my set up. Please share an example Sheet that contains the mentioned code, so I can take a better look at it.

Comment: So I solved my own problem. In trying to get you a copy of the worksheet I figured out that all it had to do with was that I had two gmail accounts logged in. I built the script with my work account, but my personal one became my primary.  Once I swapped them out it started working again.

Comment: I am glad that the problem was solved. Could you please expand your solution in an answer for documentation purposes?

Comment: Pretty sure I did explain the solution.